# Node Js + MySQL update on REST send out undefined rather than send the data to mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, rest

controller.js

```
exports.updateUser = function(req, res) {

    var user_id = req.body.user_id;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var role = req.body.role;
    var status = req.body.status;

    connection.query('UPDATE user SET name = "?", username = "?", password = md5("?"), email = "?", role = "?", status = "?" WHERE id = ?',
    [ name, username, password, email, role, status, user_id ], 
    function (error, rows, fields){
        if(error){
            console.log(error)
        } else{
            response.ok("Apdet user Sukses!", res)
        }
    });
};
```

when i clicked send, nothing happen. then i tried to change the `response.ok("Apdet user Sukses!", res)` to `console.log(response.ok("Apdet user Sukses!", res))` so i can see what happen to the data on the console. but rather than getting any data at all i get undefined.

Comment: Let's see your HTML code

Comment: what is `response`? don't see anything in your code

Comment: its fixed now!, im sorry for the incoviniences. its just a silly typo in my html. thank you for the kind repond nonetheless